# Show links according to rights in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-3

I m working on a MVC 3 application , it contain different links , i want to show the links according to the roles or rights. If Link A is to Admin thn Link A shouldnt be visble to Members right users.

How to achieve this thing in MVC ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're not using the asp membership, you could do it this way, supposing you could get the role by using the username and that the role is included in the model:

```
@{
   UserContext userDb = new UserContext();
   var user = userDb.UserModels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username.Equals(User.Identity.Name));

   if(user.Role == "Admin")
   {
      @ActionLink("Link's Name","SomeAction", "SomeController");
   }
}
```

crude sample but if that what you're looking for.

Comment: This is the same approach as describe by PieterGermishuys in the above ansswer ?

Comment: similar, yes. I thought it would be better to show an example.

Answer (score 3):

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Administrator")) {
   @Html.ActionLink("Administration", "", "Admin")
}
```

Comment: I m not using Asp.net Membership , using my own database for handling users and roles. in this scenario how to apply rights thing?

Comment: @Saad: I suggest you implement a custom RoleProvider that talks to your database. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8fw7xh74

Comment: This method still applies regardless of what you are using. The concept is sound.
@if(yourCustomImplementation.HasRights("AdministrationNode"))
{
   @Html.ActionLink("Administration"....);
}